# Facebook login dialog is broken on HTC 8s in WebBrowser control (Windows Phone)

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I use WebBrowser control (Windows Phone) to display facebook login dialog in my app. It works with Nokia Lumia 920, HTC Mozart. But facebook returns broken HTML-page for HTC 8s (It seems like facebook returns different HTML-code for each mobile device type)

How I can keep correct HTML from facebook for HTC 8s?

HTC 8s:

[image]

HTC Mozart:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First off I'd stop trying to do this yourself.

Use the NuGet FaceBookSDK that is provided by Microsoft, it makes the whole thing a lot simpler and they walk you through using a web control to properly authenticate with facebook.

Also if you are feeling adventurous they also have a separate client package which includes some WP8 controls for integrating with FB.

I wouldn't recommend doing it manually.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to use Nuget package (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook). It provides same error as I have

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issue forcing a different User Agent in WebBrowser navigate method, like this:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(loginUrl, null, "User-Agent: Mozilla 5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 710)");
```

Comment: I'm having this issue on the HTC 8s. The same code works in all the emulators and also on a nokia WP8 phone (dunno which one it was anymore). I used the different user agent and now it displays fine.